# How to rename .git folder?

Tags: git

I want to rename the git folder to something else, because I fear that my local .git folder will overwrite the remote git folder with my deployment.

Can I just rename the folder or do I have to execute a special command?

Comment: Um, sorry, but I don’t quite get the problem. How would a local folder overwrite a remote folder? Is this a bare repository or one with a work tree? If the latter, do you want to rename the worktree folder or the `.git` folder in it?

Comment: Why are you deploying a git repository to another git repository by copying files? Shouldn't you be using push?

Comment: I know that I should just push, but I don't have the rights yet, so I need to work with my local git repository, but I don't want that it overwrites the remote repository. I have setup auto deployment on save and I think that the .git folder will be uploaded to the remote server on save and overwrites it.

Comment: if the issue is because you don't have rights, then just fork it and issue pull request, or get rights.

Comment: Wait wait wait... you "don't have rights" to push to the repo, but you *do* have sufficient access to (potentially accidentally) overwrite the files that make up the repo?  I call shenanigans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename `.git` to whatever you want, but afterwards you have to either set an environment variable `GIT_DIR` or add an argument to *every* git call:

```
git --git-dir=./.definitively-not-git status
```

See [`man git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) for the nasty details.

Yes, it is exactly as inconvenient and error-prone as it sounds. So, it might be better to look into other solutions like what @mouche says, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rename the `.git` folder and still have git work, so you'll need to exclude that directory from your deployment.

If you deploy via `git push`, this isn't a problem because your `.git` directory will not be sent. If you use `rsync` or some other way of copying all the files in the folder to your remote server, use a command line option to exclude the folder.